# Simple countdown hh:mm:ss in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, countdown

How can I create a simple countdown in Android studio with a fixed start time? It should start the count down as soon as the application is opened. The preferable format is hh:mm:ss

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Android `Chronometer` class to display countdown.
Below is sample code:

```
<Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
        android:textColor="#4169E1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Chronometer" />
```